# running mule from maven not seeing mule-app.properties

Tags: spring, maven, mule

Here is my exec config:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.mule.MuleServer</mainClass>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>-config</argument>
                    <argument>src/main/app/prioritisation-api.xml</argument>
                    <argument>-classpath</argument>
                    <argument>src/main/app</argument>
                </arguments>
                <classpathScope>compile</classpathScope>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

And the error I get

`org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'protocol' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Address '${prioritisation.api.console.endpoint}' for protocol 'http' should start with http://`

This suggests to me that the mule-app.properties are not being resolved properly.  The thing is this all works in Anypoint Studio when I do Run As Maven Mule Project.  What am I missing?

EDIT:

I am trying to run mule using: `mvn exec:java -DrunMule`

Mule version: `<mule.version>3.4.0</mule.version>`

Properties are in: `src/main/app/mule-app.properties`

Maven version: `Apache Maven 3.2.1`

Comment: What do you mean by `mule-app.properties are not being resolved properly`? Can you show your full pom file? Where are those properties located? Which Maven version do you use? How you call Maven? Does it work from command line?

Comment: I have added versions etc to the question.  Properties are not being resolved properly because it is not replacing `${prioritisation.api.console.endpoint}` with the value of the property.

Answer (score 0):

Although it ran in Anypoint Studio, without this, to run with maven exec you need to add `<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:mule-app.properties" />`.  I'm not sure how it works in Anypoint (presumably also in a Mule container as well)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add your properties to a file with name `environment.properties` in the `src/main/resources` folder and add its reference using `<context:property-placeholder location="environment.properties"/>`

Comment: Thanks Gahan, am new to this forum, therefore not aware of formatting options available